# BigDecimal equals() versus compareTo()

Tags: java, equals, bigdecimal, compareto

Consider the simple test class:

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

/**
 * @author The Elite Gentleman
 *
 */
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BigDecimal x = new BigDecimal("1");
        BigDecimal y = new BigDecimal("1.00");
        System.out.println(x.equals(y));
        System.out.println(x.compareTo(y) == 0 ? "true": "false");
    }

}
```

You can (consciously) say that `x` is equal to `y` (not object reference), but when you run the program, the following result shows:

```
false
true
```

Question: What's the difference between `compareTo()` and `equals()` in `BigDecimal` that `compareTo` can determine that `x` is equal to `y`?

PS: I see that BigDecimal has an `inflate()` method on `equals()` method. What does `inflate()` do actually?

Comment: Ad `inflate()`: it's not part of the public API because it only manipulates the internal representation and has no visible effect to the "outside". So unless you really want to study the implementation of `BigDecimal` in-depth, I'd suggest you ignore this method.

Comment: A short explanation and source code snippets can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39163942/4723795)

Answer (score 283, accepted):

The answer is in [the JavaDoc of the `equals()` method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29):

> Unlike [`compareTo`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo%28java.math.BigDecimal%29), this method considers two `BigDecimal` objects equal only if they are equal in value and scale (thus 2.0 is not equal to 2.00 when compared by this method).

In other words: `equals()` checks if the `BigDecimal` objects are **exactly** the same in **every** aspect. `compareTo()` "only" compares their numeric value.

As to *why* `equals()` behaves this way, this has been answered [in this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102083/why-is-bigdecimal-equals-specified-to-compare-both-value-and-scale-individually).

Comment: That's a very tricky portion of `BigDecimal` if you don't read the JavaDoc carefully. :) - We got some strange bugs from this until we realized the difference.

Comment: Many parts of the standard API happen to act "unintuitively", when the intuitive thing would not be correct. `BigDecimal` is one such thing. Therefore one should always check the JavaDoc. *At least* once your find out something strange is going on.

Comment: Funny. After reading your answer I just checked Comparable and it states that consistence with equals "is strongly recommended (but not required)"

Comment: @SJuan76 - it is important to understand why it is *correct* that this inconsistency should exist for `BigDecimal` ...

Comment: I've asked why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102083/why-is-bigdecimal-equals-specified-to-compare-both-value-and-scale-individually

Comment: @StephenC I think it's *incorrect* that this inconsistency exists.

Comment: @MattR: There are two reasons for the behavior.  First of all, the values 1.20 and 1.2 may represent the same value, but they do not behave identically in all contexts.  For example, calling `toString()` on them will yield different values.  That may be a sufficient difference to regard them as unequal.  Secondly, it the two values compare as equal, then the values from the hash function would have to match as well.  The way BigDecimal values 1.20 and 1.2 are stored, however, is sufficiently different that computing matches hash values would be tricky.

Comment: @supercat We...discussed this four years ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102083/why-is-bigdecimal-equals-specified-to-compare-both-value-and-scale-individually

Comment: The longer I work with `java.lang.BigDecimal` the more I regret not using the money on my system as an int/long representation of the cents

Answer (score 2):

> I see that BigDecimal has an inflate() method on equals() method. What does inflate() do actually?

Basically, `inflate()` calls `BigInteger.valueOf(intCompact)` if necessary, i.e. it creates the unscaled value that is stored as a `BigInteger` from `long intCompact`. If you don't need that `BigInteger` and the unscaled value fits into a `long` `BigDecimal` seems to try to save space as long as possible.

Comment: I have no idea what you wrote (especially with the last sentence).

Comment: @The Elite Gentlement The last sentence should just say that internally `BigDecimal` keeps its unscaled value in a `long` as well as a `BigInteger`. If the `BigInteger` is not needed internally it is not created but if it is needed (e.g. when `equals` encounters an inflated and a non-inflated `BigDecimal) `inflate()` is used to create it. - To sum it up: `inflate()` handles internal conversions if necessary and since it is private it shouldn't matter for users of the class.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the correct answer would be to make the two numbers (BigDecimals), have the same scale, then we can decide about their equality. For example, are these two numbers equal?

```
1.00001 and 1.00002
```

Well, it depends on the scale. On the scale 5 (5 decimal points), no they are not the same. but on smaller decimal precisions (scale 4 and lower) they are considered equal.
So I suggest make the scale of the two numbers equal and then compare them.

Answer (score -18):

You can also compare with double value

```
BigDecimal a= new BigDecimal("1.1"); BigDecimal b =new BigDecimal("1.1");
System.out.println(a.doubleValue()==b.doubleValue());
```

Comment: Please avoid this solution as much as possible. Even doubles should be compared with "epsilon". There is no sense to have BigDecimal and compare it as doubles..there is very high probability you will shoot your own leg.

Comment: Douuble values must be compared using epsillons

Comment: The crutches even on stackoverflow