# java.math.BigDecimal comparison: the same value represented in different formats don't match

Tags: java, bigdecimal

The following code:

```
 BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("8900");
 BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("8.9E+3");

 System.out.println(a.equals(b));
```

prints *false*. Why is so, if *mathematically* those numbers are equal?

[image: internal representation]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787142/bigdecimal-equals-versus-compareto

Comment: @Reimeus just noticed the comment. Closing as duplicate. #

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `compareTo()`:

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal("8900");
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("8.9E+3");

System.out.println(a.compareTo(b) == 0);
```