# How to use comparison operators like >, =, < on BigDecimal

Tags: java, operator-keyword, bigdecimal

I have a domain class with `unitPrice` set as `BigDecimal` data type. Now I am trying to create a method to compare price but it seems like I can't have comparison operators in `BigDecimal` data type. Do I have to change data type or is there other way around?

Comment: since `BigDecimal` is an `Object`, no this doesn´t work. But you could simply subtract one from each other and check if the resulting value is `<0`, `==0` or `>0`. Otherwise you could go the standard way with the provided methods from [BigDecimal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787142/bigdecimal-equals-versus-compareto)

Comment: That why there is a `compareTo` method which returns -1, 0 or 1. Which is basically the [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html).

Comment: https://github.com/mortezaadi/bigdecimal-utils

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Every object of the Class `BigDecimal` has a method [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo-java.math.BigDecimal-) you can use to compare it to another BigDecimal. The result of `compareTo` is then compared `> 0`, `== 0` or `< 0` depending on what you need. Read the documentation and you will find out.

The operators `==`, `<`, `>` and so on can only be used on primitive data types like `int`, `long`, `double` or their wrapper classes like `Integer`and `Double`.

From the documentation of `compareTo`:

> Compares this `BigDecimal` with the specified `BigDecimal`.
>
> Two `BigDecimal`
>   objects that are equal in value but have a different scale (like 2.0
>   and 2.00) are considered equal by this method. This method is provided
>   in preference to individual methods for each of the six boolean
>   comparison operators (<, ==, >, >=, !=, <=). The suggested idiom for
>   performing these comparisons is: `(x.compareTo(y) <op> 0)`, where `<op>`
>   is one of the six comparison operators.
>
> Returns:
>   -1, 0, or 1 as this BigDecimal is numerically less than, equal to, or greater than val.

Comment: But does the compareTo method helps in finding like whether the price is greater than, equals to or lower than?

Comment: Yes. That information is in the link provided in the answer.

Comment: @user3127109 yes, `a.compareTo(b)` returns a number greater than zero if `a > b`, `0` if `a == b`, and less than zero if `a < b`.

Answer (score 271):

To be short:

```
firstBigDecimal.compareTo(secondBigDecimal) < 0   // "<"
firstBigDecimal.compareTo(secondBigDecimal) > 0   // ">"    
firstBigDecimal.compareTo(secondBigDecimal) == 0  // "=="  
firstBigDecimal.compareTo(secondBigDecimal) != 0  // "!="  
firstBigDecimal.compareTo(secondBigDecimal) >= 0  // ">="    
firstBigDecimal.compareTo(secondBigDecimal) <= 0  // "<="
```

Answer (score 30):

Use the [`compareTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo-java.math.BigDecimal-) method of BigDecimal :

> public int compareTo(BigDecimal val) Compares this BigDecimal with the
>   specified BigDecimal.
>
> ```
> Returns:
> -1, 0, or 1 as this BigDecimal is numerically less than, equal to, or greater than val.
> ```

Answer (score 25):

Here is an example for all six boolean comparison operators (<, ==, >, >=, !=, <=):

```
BigDecimal big10 = new BigDecimal(10);
BigDecimal big20 = new BigDecimal(20);

System.out.println(big10.compareTo(big20) < -1);  // false
System.out.println(big10.compareTo(big20) <= -1); // true
System.out.println(big10.compareTo(big20) == -1); // true
System.out.println(big10.compareTo(big20) >= -1); // true
System.out.println(big10.compareTo(big20) > -1);  // false
System.out.println(big10.compareTo(big20) != -1); // false

System.out.println(big10.compareTo(big20) < 0);   // true
System.out.println(big10.compareTo(big20) <= 0);  // true
System.out.println(big10.compareTo(big20) == 0);  // false
System.out.println(big10.compareTo(big20) >= 0);  // false
System.out.println(big10.compareTo(big20) > 0);   // false
System.out.println(big10.compareTo(big20) != 0);  // true

System.out.println(big10.compareTo(big20) < 1);   // true
System.out.println(big10.compareTo(big20) <= 1);  // true
System.out.println(big10.compareTo(big20) == 1);  // false
System.out.println(big10.compareTo(big20) >= 1);  // false
System.out.println(big10.compareTo(big20) > 1);   // false
System.out.println(big10.compareTo(big20) != 1);  // true
```

Answer (score 18):

You can use method named `compareTo`, `x.compareTo(y)`. It will return 0 if x and y are equal, 1 if x is greater than y and -1 if x is smaller than y

Answer (score 15):

Alternatively, if you're already using `commons-lang3` (version `3.10` and up), you can leverage their `ComparableUtils` API like so:

```
import static org.apache.commons.lang3.compare.ComparableUtils.is;

var areEqual = is(first).equalTo(second);
var isGreater = is(first).greaterThan(second);
var isLess = is(first).lessThan(second);
var isBetween = is(first).between(second, third);
// etc.
```

Nowadays, most large projects include `commons-lang3` as a dependency, anyway.

Answer (score 10):

#### Discussion

This thread has plenty of answers stating that the [BigDecimal.compareTo(BigDecimal)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo-java.math.BigDecimal-) method is the one to use to compare [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instances. I just wanted to add for anyone not experienced with using the [BigDecimal.compareTo(BigDecimal)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo-java.math.BigDecimal-) method: Be careful with how you create your [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instances. For example:

- `new BigDecimal(0.8)` will create a `BigDecimal` instance with a value which is *not* exactly `0.8` and which has a scale of 50+,
- `new BigDecimal("0.8")` will create a `BigDecimal` instance with a value which *is* exactly `0.8` and which has a scale of 1.

These two [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instances are unequal according to the [BigDecimal.compareTo(BigDecimal)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo-java.math.BigDecimal-) method because their values are unequal when the scale is not limited to a few decimal places.

#### Summary

Firstly, be careful to create your `BigDecimal` instances with the `BigDecimal(String val)` constructor or the `BigDecimal.valueOf(double val)` method rather than the `BigDecimal(double val)` constructor. Secondly, note that you can limit the scale of [BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instances prior to comparing them by means of the [BigDecimal.setScale(int newScale, RoundingMode roundingMode)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale-int-java.math.RoundingMode-) method.

Answer (score 6):

[`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) isn't a primitive, so you cannot use the `<`, `>` operators. However, since it's a [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), you can use the [`compareTo(BigDecimal)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo-java.math.BigDecimal-) to the same effect. E.g.:

```
public class Domain {
    private BigDecimal unitPrice;

    public boolean isCheaperThan(BigDecimal other) {
        return unitPirce.compareTo(other.unitPrice) < 0;
    }

    // etc...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can follow this utility static method and Operator enum for comparing the two numbers:

```
public static boolean check(BigDecimal firstNum, Operator operator, BigDecimal secondNum) {
    switch (operator) {
        case EQUALS:
            return firstNum.compareTo(secondNum) == 0;
        case LESS_THAN:
            return firstNum.compareTo(secondNum) < 0;
        case LESS_THAN_OR_EQUALS:
            return firstNum.compareTo(secondNum) <= 0;
        case GREATER_THAN:
            return firstNum.compareTo(secondNum) > 0;
        case GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUALS:
            return firstNum.compareTo(secondNum) >= 0;
    }

    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Will never reach here");
}

public enum Operator {
    LESS_THAN, LESS_THAN_OR_EQUALS, GREATER_THAN, GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUALS, EQUALS
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example to compare two `BigDecimal` values.

```
public class BigDecimalDemo {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      // create 2 BigDecimal objects
      BigDecimal bg1, bg2;

      bg1 = new BigDecimal("10");
      bg2 = new BigDecimal("20");

      //create int object
      int res;

      res = bg1.compareTo(bg2); // compare bg1 with bg2

      String str1 = "Both values are equal ";
      String str2 = "First Value is greater ";
      String str3 = "Second value is greater";

      if( res == 0 )
         System.out.println( str1 );
      else if( res == 1 )
         System.out.println( str2 );
      else if( res == -1 )
         System.out.println( str3 );
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using *com.ibm.etools.marshall.util.BigDecimalRange* util class of IBM one can compare if *BigDecimal* in range.

```
boolean isCalculatedSumInRange = BigDecimalRange.isInRange(low, high, calculatedSum);
```