# How to fix java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.math.BigDecimal error for variable expression?

Tags: jasper-reports, bigdecimal

I have a variable that returns an error when included in the report (preview) but no error when compiling.

The variable is supposed to output 2 digit number on the report based on the amount of a field.

I have a field `$F{total balance}` of `java.lang.String` type and a variable `$V{Total_balance_num}` that converts it to a number. The variable `$V{Total_balance_num}` has type `java.math.BigDecimal`:

```
<variable name="Total balance num" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[new Double(Double.parseDouble($F{total_balance}))]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

The main part is to print a different 2 digit number on the report based on the amount of `$V{Total_balance_num}`. This variable is called `$V{groups}` of type `java.lang.String`:

```
<variable name="groups" class="java.lang.String">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{Total balance num}.doubleValue() <= new java.math.BigDecimal(250).doubleValue() ? "15":
($V{Total balance num}.doubleValue() <= new java.math.BigDecimal(1000).doubleValue() ? "30":
($V{Total balance num}.doubleValue() <= new java.math.BigDecimal(10000).doubleValue() ? "30" :
  ($V{Total balance num}.doubleValue() <= new java.math.BigDecimal(50000).doubleValue() ? "40":"0"
   )
 ))]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

I have to start from the field total balance that is of type string.
When compiling there is no error. But if I create a field to output the variable and then click on preview I get this error:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.jrexpressionevalexception error evaluating expression
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression: 
Source text: $V{Total_balance_num}.doubleValue() <= new java.math.BigDecimal(250).doubleValue() ? "15":($V{Total_balance_num}.doubleValue() <= new java.math.BigDecimal(1000).doubleValue() ? "30"  ($V{Total_balance_num}.doubleValue() <= new java.math.BigDecimal(10000).doubleValue() ? "30" :   ($V{Total_balance_num}.doubleValue() <= new java.math.BigDecimal(50000).doubleValue() ? "40":"0"    )  )  ) 
at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportControler.fillReport(ReportControler.java:466) 
..
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression : 
    Source text : $V{Total_balance_num}.doubleValue() <= new java.math.BigDecimal(250).doubleValue() ? "15":($V{Total_balance_num}.doubleValue() <= new java.math.BigDecimal(1000).doubleValue() ? "30":   ($V{Total_balance_num}.doubleValue() <= new java.math.BigDecimal(10000).doubleValue() ? "30"    ($V{Total_balance_num}.doubleValue() <= new java.math.BigDecimal(50000).doubleValue() ? "40":"0")     )      ) 
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluateEstimated(JREvaluator.java:327) 
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.math.BigDecimal at S01_1556196241282_981700.evaluateEstimated(S01_1556196241282_981700:935) 
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluateEstimated(JREvaluator.java:314) ... 9 more
```

Sample code to reporoduce the issue:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="S01" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="595" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="9b44ef22-1966-46f3-acbe-4bfb10170dbc">
    <queryString language="xPath">
        <![CDATA[/letter/fields]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="total_balance" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[total_balance]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[name]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <variable name="Total balance num" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[new Double(Double.parseDouble($F{total_balance}))]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <variable name="groups" class="java.lang.String">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{Total balance num}.doubleValue() <= new java.math.BigDecimal(250).doubleValue() ? "15":
    ($V{Total balance num}.doubleValue() <= new java.math.BigDecimal(1000).doubleValue() ? "30":
    ($V{Total balance num}.doubleValue() <= new java.math.BigDecimal(10000).doubleValue() ? "30" :
      ($V{Total balance num}.doubleValue() <= new java.math.BigDecimal(50000).doubleValue() ? "40":"0"
       )
     )
  )]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <detail>
        <band height="841" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="62" y="136" width="238" height="15" uuid="85a6b895-3aa5-4607-b2e7-8959da279c1d">
                </reportElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="110" y="200" width="314" height="20" uuid="4d2918f5-b6d9-4d81-8be6-e68e1c19bd32"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <text><![CDATA[TEST TEXT]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

And also xml code to use as an adaptor for the input data (save it as xml -> create new data adapter in Jaspersoft studio -> choose XML document -> select the file and choose use the report Xpath expression when filling the report -> finish)

```
<letter>
    <fields>
      <name>Jeff</name>
      <total_balance>14576.88</total_balance>
    </fields>
</letter>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reminder. I added the sample code to reproduce the issue to my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What is wrong?

The expression of `groups` variable is right. You got exception because another expression is wrong:

```
<variable name="Total balance num" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[new Double(Double.parseDouble($F{total_balance}))]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

You got `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.math.BigDecimal` exception because you are trying to assign double value to object of *BigDecimal* type.

The right version is:

```
<variable name="Total balance num" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{total_balance} == null || $F{total_balance}.length() == 0 ? BigDecimal.ZERO : new BigDecimal($F{total_balance})]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

You can get ***NumberFormatException*** with this expression. To prevent this problem you can add check that `$F{total_balance}` is numeric, for example with help of [*org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.isNumeric*](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isNumeric-java.lang.CharSequence-) method. In this case you need to add import to *jrxml* and add [*Apache Commons Lang*](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) library to classpath.

The snippet of *jrxml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport ... />
    <!-- ... -->
    <import value="org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils"/>
    <!-- ... -->
    <variable name="Total balance num" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[StringUtils.isNumeric($F{total_balance}) ? new BigDecimal($F{total_balance}) : BigDecimal.ZERO]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
```

#### Optimization 1. Using right type of field

You can declare field as `<field name="total_balance" class="java.math.BigDecimal">`. In this case your report will be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="S01" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="595" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="9b44ef22-1966-46f3-acbe-4bfb10170dbc">
    <queryString language="xPath">
        <![CDATA[/letter/fields]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="total_balance" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[total_balance]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[name]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <variable name="groups" class="java.lang.String">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{total_balance}.doubleValue() <= new java.math.BigDecimal(250).doubleValue() ? "15":
    ($F{total_balance}.doubleValue() <= new java.math.BigDecimal(1000).doubleValue() ? "30":
    ($F{total_balance}.doubleValue() <= new java.math.BigDecimal(10000).doubleValue() ? "30" :
      ($F{total_balance}.doubleValue() <= new java.math.BigDecimal(50000).doubleValue() ? "40":"0"
       )
     )
  )]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <detail>
        <band height="30" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="23" y="0" width="238" height="15" uuid="85a6b895-3aa5-4607-b2e7-8959da279c1d"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="23" y="15" width="240" height="15" uuid="33a58249-b338-4741-ad5a-4c67846cf006">
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{groups}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

With your test data this version of report works well.

#### Optimization 2. Compare BigDecimal objects in right manner

The right method for comparing *BigDecimal* object is to use [*BigDecimal.compareTo(BigDecimal)*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo(java.math.BigDecimal)) method.

---

#### More info:

- [Convert double to BigDecimal and set BigDecimal Precision](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12395281/876298)
- [Convert string to BigDecimal in java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28783918/876298)
- [How to check if a String is numeric in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1102891/876298)
- [How to use comparison operators like >, =, < on BigDecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34677644/876298)

Comment: You are a life saver! Thank you for your help and fast response Alex  :)