# How can I compare BigDecimals to make my tests pass?

Tags: java, junit, bigdecimal

I have the following same strange situation into a `JUnit` test.

So I have this test method:

```
@Test
public void getNavInfoTest() throws ParseException {

    TirAliquotaRamoI expectedObject = new TirAliquotaRamoI();

    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date date;

    date = formatter.parse("2015-08-01");

    Date dataInizio = formatter.parse("2015-08-01");
    Date dataFine = formatter.parse("2100-12-31");

    expectedObject.setDataElaborazione(date);
    expectedObject.setTassoLordoAnnuoAppl(BigDecimal.ZERO);
    expectedObject.setTassoGiornalieroNetto(BigDecimal.ZERO);
    expectedObject.setAliquota(BigDecimal.ONE);
    expectedObject.setDataInizio(dataInizio);
    expectedObject.setDataFine(dataFine);

    TirAliquotaRamoI tirAliquotaRamoI = pucManager.getNavInfo(date);

    assertEquals(tirAliquotaRamoI.getAliquota(), expectedObject.getAliquota());

}
```

At the end I am simply testing if the `tirAliquotaRamoI.getAliquota()` (obtained from a DB query) have the same value of the same field defined for the created `expectedObject`:

```
assertEquals(tirAliquotaRamoI.getAliquota(), expectedObject.getAliquota());
```

So the field for the expected object is created using the `BigDecimal.ONE` constand and using the debugger I can see that its value is `1`.

And the `tirAliquotaRamoI.getAliquota()` obtaind value is `1.000000000`

So, in theory, both represent the same value 1 but the test fail and I obtain:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<1.000000000> but was:<1>
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:834)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:144)
    at com.fideuram.dbmanager.PucManagerTest.getNavInfoTest(PucManagerTest.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Why if both represent the ame 1.0 value? How can I fix this issue to pass the test?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The reason is how the `BigDecimal` `equals` is implemented. `BigDecimal.ONE` is constructed as  `new BigDecimal(BigInteger.ONE, 1, 0, 1)`. The equals method is implemented in the following way (from JDK source code):

```
public boolean equals(Object x) {
    if (!(x instanceof BigDecimal))
        return false;
    BigDecimal xDec = (BigDecimal) x;
    if (x == this)
        return true;
    if (scale != xDec.scale)
        return false;
    long s = this.intCompact;
    long xs = xDec.intCompact;
    if (s != INFLATED) {
        if (xs == INFLATED)
            xs = compactValFor(xDec.intVal);
        return xs == s;
    } else if (xs != INFLATED)
        return xs == compactValFor(this.intVal);

    return this.inflated().equals(xDec.inflated());
}
```

So two `BigDecimals` are equal only if they have the same scale. `ONE`s scale is smaller than returned `BigDecimal`'s so they're not equal.

I saw some answers saying that you can take *floatValue* of `BigDecimal`. Well, you can't. `BigDecimal` is used when dealing with bigger numbers so in this certain case it would work, but is a bad pattern.

But fortunately we can use `compareTo` method!

```
assertTrue(tirAliquotaRamoI.getAliquota().compareTo(expectedObject.getAliquota()) == 0);
```

It's not perfect but will work!

Comment: why isn't it perfect?

Comment: @Line the line is quite long first of all :)

Answer (score 10):

BigDecimal comparison always uses the scale as well, therefore your tests are failing.

See [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) for details.

If you are interested only in the value and not the scale, then consider using stripTrailingZeros() when comparing.

```
assertEquals(
    tirAliquotaRamoI.getAliquota().stripTrailingZeros(),
    expectedObject.getAliquota().stripTrailingZeros()
);
```

Answer (score 7):

It looks to me like they have different [scales](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal(java.math.BigInteger)).

Try [compareTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#compareTo%28java.math.BigDecimal%29):

```
 assertEquals(0, tirAliquotaRamoI.compareTo(expectedObject.getAliquota());
```

Or if you care about matching the scales then you'll have to change the scale on either object using setScale(int newScale) to match the other.

Hope that helps.

Thanks to @David SN for the correction.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that when the test fails you won't know why, as in you'll get no diagnostics of what the actual value is

Comment: `assertTrue` has a boolean parameter. You should use  `assertTrue(tirAliquotaRamoI.compareTo(expectedObject.getAliquota() == 0);` or `assertEquals(0, tirAliquotaRamoI.compareTo(expectedObject.getAliquota());`

Comment: or using stripTrailingZeroes() as in my example

Comment: tddmonkey: But isn't this test just to ensure that both values are equal?

DavidSN: I can't believe I missed that, thanks I'll edit the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Although I don't know JUnit methods, I guess the problem relates to:

> public boolean equals(Object x)
>
> Compares this BigDecimal with the specified Object for equality.
>   Unlike compareTo, this method considers two BigDecimal objects equal
>   only if they are equal in value and scale (thus 2.0 is not equal to
>   2.00 when compared by this method).

(see [BigDecimal.equals() docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29))

Probably, `assertEquals()` is using the aforementioned method, which compares both the *value* and the *scale* of your numbers.

You may want to try an approach with [assertTrue()](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertTrue%28boolean%29) as suggested in [x870eaddd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39163961/3127111)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
assertEquals((int)tirAliquotaRamoI.getAliquota(), (int)expectedObject.getAliquota());
```

I think `AssertEquals` can only compare two variable from same type (`int` to `int`, `double` to `double`...). In your test, one is a decimal and the other is not, so it probably can't compare them.

Comment: Both are BigDecimal and could have decimal digits

Answer (score 0):

What is data type for `tirAliquotaRamoI.getAliquota()`? Is it `BigDecimal` too because `BigDecimal.ONE` is a `BigDecimal` data type.

If tirAliquotaRamoI.getAliquota() is Long or Int or Float, you can use

`assertEquals(tirAliquotaRamoI.getAliquota(), BigDecimal.ONE.intValue())`

or

`assertEquals(tirAliquotaRamoI.getAliquota(), BigDecimal.ONE.longValue())`