# Java Bigdecimal compare issue

Tags: java, bigdecimal

i have a question about bigdecimal compare. currently, i have two values ,they have different source, the first one is 748.30 which query from database, i use the `resultSet.getBigDecimal(columnValue)`, then i get 748.30, and the second value is query by **Spring-data-jpa** which from another database, the value is `748.3000`, when i use the method `BigDecimal.compare` to compare these two values, and i got the result is not 0, i am very confused, can you help me?

Comment: Can you include your actual comparison code?

Comment: What is the value displayed when you use SQL to query the 2 different data?

Comment: BigDecimal does not have a method `compare`. It does have a method `compareTo`. When you run `System.out.println(new BigDecimal("748.30").compareTo(new BigDecimal("748.3000")));`, the output is 0 (**zero**), unlike your question says. So there is something else going on in your application.

Comment: A useful read is [BigDecimal equals() versus compareTo()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787142/bigdecimal-equals-versus-compareto)

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen, i have a class named tradeRecord, i want to compare the balnace, the code is `tradeRecord.setBalance(resultSet.getBigDecimal("surplus_money"));`, and the other class is cardinfo, the balance property of cardinfo is also a bigDecimal, and the scale is 4, the value is setted by spring-data-jpa, the compare code is 'lastAskbalance.add(tradeRecord.getTradeAmount().multiply(inOutValue)).compareTo(tradeRecord.getBalance()) != 0'

Comment: Hi @ErwinBolwidt, yes , i tried this , get the result as you , so i am very confused.

Comment: @maoningchuan: Don't put your code and explanation in a comment, put it in your question. Edit your question and add the code there. Also make the text a little bit more readable by formatting it a little better (use paragraphs, etc.).