# Best way to compare BigDecimal with other variables?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

```
                if (BigDecimal.ZERO == actualSettlementAmountDetail) {
```

or

```
                if (BigDecimal.ZERO.equals(actualSettlementAmountDetail)) {
```

where **actualSettlementAmountDetail** is a BigDecimal.

```
BigDecimal actualSettlementAmountDetail;
```

I am solving code quality issues reported by CAST and the quality rule states that -

> Check usage of '==' and '!=' on objects

Comment: remember that, whenever you have the opportunity to use `equals` don't think about the `"=="`anymore

Comment: use the equals method

Comment: Note that in some cases you might want to use `compareTo()` instead of `equals()`: [BigDecimal equals() versus compareTo()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6787142/2759108)

Comment: @Maurice: No, use `compareTo()`. `equals()` will also fail if one BigDecimal is BigDecimal.ZERO and the other has a value like .0.000

Comment: FWIW, as I said, this is not a duplicate. Equals only returns true if the BigDecimals are exactly equal, i.e. have the same value and scale. CompareTo also returns true if they have a different scale, but othrwise same value, i.e. it compares 0.1 and 0.1000 as equal. So for BigDecimal, things are slightly different and equals() is the wrong method.