# How to Throw exception using Stream on List when try to find element?

Tags: java, list, exception, java-stream, option-type

I want to throw an exception using stream when I find an element by condition

```
 myList.stream()
      .filter(d -> (d.getNetPrice() != new BigDecimal(0)))
      .findAny()
      .orElseThrow(
          () -> new DocumentRequestException("The product has 0 'NetPrice' as a value"));
```

for request

```
{
        "sku": "123",
        "quantity": 3,
        "description": "pc",
        "netPrice": 16806,
        "amount": 50418
    },
    {
        "sku": "1234",
        "quantity": 2,
        "description": "notebook",
        "netPrice": 0,
        "amount": 0
    }
```

So for that example I want the exception because the list contains one element with 'netPrice' = 0 but the code return the Pc element and nothing else happend

how can I fix it?

Comment: Your code uses `orElseThrow`, which throws if the Optional is *absent*, i.e. if you didn't find any element. Use ifPresent(). Or use an if block with anyMatch. And don't compare objects with `==`. Use equals() in general, and use compareTo with BigDecimal.

Comment: If I can add one thing to improve your code then I would advise you do not use exceptions to control your code.

Comment: Also note that BigDecimal.ZERO exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `anyMatch` to perform an `if` check and throw the exception as:

```
if(myList.stream().anyMatch(d -> d.getNetPrice().equals(BigDecimal.ZERO)) {
    throw new DocumentRequestException("The product has 0 'NetPrice' as a value")
}
```

Comment: This answer works but what happen with orElseThrow?

Comment: @TuGordoBello I explained that in the first comment under your question, 21 minutes ago.

Comment: [Careful using `equals` with `BigDecimal`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6787142/6395627). @TuGordoBello