# AssertJ fails to assert BigDecimal equality without scale

Tags: java, junit, assertj

I am running assertions like so:

```
assertThat(obj.getTotal()).isEqualTo(BigDecimal.valueOf(4))
```

I am getting

> Expecting:
> <4.00>
> to be equal to:
> <4>

so then I tried

```
assertThat(obj.getTotal()).isEqualTo(BigDecimal.valueOf(4.00))
```

> Expecting:
> <4.00>
> to be equal to:
> <4.0>

I found a workaround in which I would set the scale of expected value `4` to `4.00`, but it seems quite irritating that I have to do so for all BigDecimal variables in my tests. Is there a better way from AssertJ that I am unaware of?

Comment: The underlying issue is not with AssertJ, but that [`BigDecimal` has a weird definition of its `equal` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787142/bigdecimal-equals-versus-compareto).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use `isEqualByComparingTo` or `usingComparator` that use `BigDecimal.compareTo` which compares the actual numeric value. The `equals` method which is the default assertj uses does the following according to [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#equals-java.lang.Object-):

> Unlike compareTo, this method considers two BigDecimal objects equal only if they are equal in value and scale (thus 2.0 is not equal to 2.00 when compared by this method).

So you can do:

```
    assertThat(obj.getTotal())
        .usingComparator(BigDecimal::compareTo)
        .isEqualTo(BigDecimal.valueOf(4.00));
```

or simply:

```
assertThat(obj.getTotal())
    .isEqualByComparingTo(BigDecimal.valueOf(4.00));
```

**To use with `Iterable` and `extracting` assertions:**

```
    assertThat(asList(new Trade("1", new BigDecimal("5.200")), new Trade("2", new BigDecimal("4.00"))))
        .extracting(Trade::getId, Trade::getAmount)
        .usingComparatorForType(BigDecimal::compareTo, BigDecimal.class)
        .usingRecursiveFieldByFieldElementComparator()
        .containsExactlyInAnyOrder(tuple("1", new BigDecimal("5.2")), tuple("2", new BigDecimal("4")));
```

Comment: This is exactly why `isEqualByComparingTo` assertion is available.

Comment: This fails though when comparing an iterable with extracting with tuples :(

Comment: @Kango_V You can use `usingComparatorForType` to assert `Iterable`s with `extracting`. I have updated the answer with an example for it.

Comment: works flawlessly!

Comment: Since 3.20.0 the comparison won't use any comparators set with:
`usingComparatorForType(Comparator, Class)`. Equivalent would be:
`usingRecursiveFieldByFieldElementComparator(RecursiveComparisonConfiguration.builder().withComparatorForType(BigDecimal::compareTo, BigDecimal.class).build())`

Comment: Note that using `new BigDecimal("1345.31")` did the trick for me instead of `new BigDecimal(1345.31)`

Answer (score 1):

In case you are comparing elements in collections, since AssertJ 3.20.0, you must use usingRecursiveFieldByFieldElementComparator(RecursiveComparisonConfiguration):

```
import org.assertj.core.api.recursive.comparison.RecursiveComparisonConfiguration;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

import static java.util.Collections.singleton;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

public class BigDecimalTests {

static class Item {
    final BigDecimal length;

    public Item(BigDecimal length) {
        this.length = length;
    }

    static Item of(String length) {
        return new Item(new BigDecimal(length));
    }
}

@Test
void fail_1() {
    assertThat(singleton(Item.of("1.0")))
            .usingComparatorForType(BigDecimal::compareTo, BigDecimal.class)
            .containsExactly(Item.of("1"));
}

@Test
void fail_2() { // OK with AssertJ < 3.20.0
    assertThat(singleton(Item.of("1.0")))
            .usingComparatorForType(BigDecimal::compareTo, BigDecimal.class)
            .usingRecursiveFieldByFieldElementComparator()
            .containsExactly(Item.of("1"));
}

@Test
void fail_3() { // OK with AssertJ < 3.20.0
    assertThat(singleton(Item.of("1.0")))
            .usingRecursiveFieldByFieldElementComparator()
            .usingComparatorForType(BigDecimal::compareTo, BigDecimal.class)
            .containsExactly(Item.of("1"));
}

@Test
void ok() {
    assertThat(singleton(Item.of("1.0")))
            .usingRecursiveFieldByFieldElementComparator(
                    RecursiveComparisonConfiguration.builder()
                            .withComparatorForType(BigDecimal::compareTo, BigDecimal.class)
                            .build())
            .containsExactly(Item.of("1"));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @laurent's answer.

If you need a recursive comparison(eg you trying to compare two objects that have `BigDecimal` fields) the following worked for me with assertJ 3.17.1:

```
assertThat(objectWithBigDecimalField)
  .usingComparatorForType(BigDecimal::compareTo, BigDecimal.class)
  .usingRecursiveComparison()
  .isEqualTo(otherObjectWithBigDecimalField)
```

Answer (score -3):

Try `java.math.BigDecimal.stripTrailingZeros()` method, like this:

```java
// AssertJ
assertThat(obj.getTotal().stripTrailingZeros()).isEqualTo(BigDecimal.valueOf(4));

// Junit
assertEquals(BigDecimal.valueOf(4), obj.getTotal().stripTrailingZeros());
```

Comment: Why did this answer get a negative score??

Comment: I don't know, seems to work in most cases; but you forgot about the engineering notation: `stripTrailingZeros()` does not help with `BigDecimal("1E+2") != BigDecimal("100")`.