# How to find the inverse of a matrix using Apache Commons Math library in Java?

Tags: java, linear-algebra

I'm trying to find the inverse of a matrix using the Apache Commons Math Library.

Below is my attempt at doing just that:

```
BigReal[][] leftMatrixData = new BigReal[][] {
    { new BigReal(1), new BigReal(0), new BigReal(0), new BigReal(0) },
    { new BigReal(1), new BigReal(0), new BigReal(1), new BigReal(0) },
    { new BigReal(1), new BigReal(1), new BigReal(0), new BigReal(0) },
    { new BigReal(1), new BigReal(1), new BigReal(1), new BigReal(1) },
};

FieldMatrix<BigReal> leftMatrix = MatrixUtils.createFieldMatrix(leftMatrixData);
FieldMatrix<BigReal> leftMatrixInverse = new FieldLUDecomposition<>(leftMatrix)
    .getSolver()
    .getInverse();
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
org.apache.commons.math3.exception.MathArithmeticException: zero not allowed here

    at org.apache.commons.math3.util.BigReal.divide(BigReal.java:255)
    at org.apache.commons.math3.util.BigReal.divide(BigReal.java:39)
    at org.apache.commons.math3.linear.FieldLUDecomposition.<init>(FieldLUDecomposition.java:160)
```

When I go to line 160 of `FieldLUDecomposition.java` per the above error message, I see that the library thinks this matrix is Singular i.e. it thinks it has no inverse:

```
public T getDeterminant() {
    if (this.singular) { <---- this is line 160
        return (FieldElement)this.field.getZero();
    } else {
        int m = this.pivot.length;
        T determinant = this.even ? (FieldElement)this.field.getOne() : (FieldElement)((FieldElement)this.field.getZero()).subtract(this.field.getOne());
```

However, doing a quick check on WolframAlpha shows that this matrix has a non-zero determinant and indeed has an inverse:

[image]

**So the question is - what am I doing wrong and how do I find the inverse of my matrix? Am I using the wrong solver?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Below is based on apache common math 3.6.1*

A [ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MATH-1617) is raised concerning this issue, I submitted a patch to fix the problem and the fix version will be 4.0 (not yet released as of 2021-07-19)

The reason of issue is `equals` method in `BigReal`

```
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (this == other){
            return true;
        }

        if (other instanceof BigReal){
            return d.equals(((BigReal) other).d);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

where d is `BigDecimal`, the backing value of `BigReal`. This cause equals comparison return undesired result when two `BigReal` has `d` [with same value but different scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787142/bigdecimal-equals-versus-compareto), and cause error when initializing `FieldLUDecomposition`. For `BigDecimal` we should check

```java
    return d.compareTo((BigReal) other) == 0;
```

instead.

### Solution:

1. Check if [workaround section](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MATH-1617?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=17382817#comment-17382817)(Copy `BigReal` as local class and change `equals`) helps.
2. Wait for version 4.0 release.
3. If double value matrix is acceptable,
   Use [`RealMatrix`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6/org/apache/commons/math3/linear/RealMatrix.html) instead, and `MatrixUtils` provide handy [`inverse`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6/org/apache/commons/math3/linear/MatrixUtils.html#inverse(org.apache.commons.math3.linear.RealMatrix)) method

```java
import org.apache.commons.math3.linear.MatrixUtils;
import org.apache.commons.math3.linear.RealMatrix;

public class CalculateInverse {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[][] matrixData = new double[][]{
                {1, 0, 0, 0},
                {1, 0, 1, 0},
                {1, 1, 0, 0},
                {1, 1, 1, 1}
        };
        RealMatrix matrix = MatrixUtils.createRealMatrix(matrixData);
        RealMatrix inverse = MatrixUtils.inverse(matrix);
        System.out.println(inverse);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately, I would really like to keep things in BigDecimal for my use case in my code. I just simplified my example to 1s and 0s to show that I'm struggling to find inverses when I use a matrix consisting of BigDecimals and I don't know why. I think it might be a bug but I'm not sure since I'm new to using the Apache Commons Math library.

Comment: After some debugging, I think there is some issue in the library, I raised a ticket for the issue and updated the answer.