# JSON path with big decimal Expected: is <1000> but: was <1000>

Tags: java, junit5

My test with Junit5 doesn't pass.

`JSON path "$.balance" Expected: is <1000> but: was <1000>`

I used the tree following modes. First one is the method that returns the initial error.

Other two Java complains with "cannot cast from BigDecimal to Integer".

Where is my wrong?

```java
BigDecimal balance = new BigDecimal(1000);
        
when(bankAccountTransactionsService.balance()).thenReturn(balance);
        
mvc.perform(get("/api/v1/balance")).andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.balance", Matchers.comparesEqualTo(bankAccountTransactionsService.balance())));
```

```java
mvc.perform(get("/api/v1/balance")).andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.balance", Matchers.comparesEqualTo(balance)));
```

```java
mvc.perform(get("/api/v1/balance")).andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.balance", is(balance)));
```

Comment: related: [BigDecimal equals() versus compareTo()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787142/bigdecimal-equals-versus-compareto)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because the types do not match. You can fix it with `balance.intVal()`:

```
BigDecimal balance = new BigDecimal(1000);
when(bankAccountTransactionsService.balance()).thenReturn(balance);
mvc.perform(get("/api/v1/balance")).andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.balance", is(balance.intVal())));
```

Comment: and what if balance is not integer value? Use double? In that case we can stumble upon precision problems